Size Error on YOLOv8 label format for pose estimation
Here is a sample label file:
0 0.643712 0.548266 0.0960109 0.057663 0.595707 0.519435 2 0.646533 0.526217 2 0.682304 0.548261 2 0.691717 0.577098 2
5 0.547212 0.54338 0.0545761 0.0753696 0.519924 0.581065 2 0.539413 0.574652 2 0.554228 0.53937 2 0.5745 0.505696 2
The yamal files show:
kpt_shape: [17, 3]
nc = 2
YOLO complains with:
rain: WARNING ⚠️ /content/datasets/echo-pose/images/train/E8F3E-9_M.jpg: ignoring corrupt image/label: labels require 56 columns each
I count 51?  Where are the other columns coming from?

The pose estimation label format is the following:

Object class index: An integer representing the class of the object (e.g., 0 for person, 1 for car, etc.).
Object center coordinates: The x and y coordinates of the center of the object, normalized between 0 and 1.
Object width and height: The width and height of the object, normalized between 0 and 1.
Object keypoint coordinates: The keypoints of the object, normalized between 0 and 1.

For a number of dims = 3 it will be:
<class-index> <x> <y> <width> <height> <px1> <py1> <p1-visibility> <px2> <py2> <p2-visibility> <pxn> <pyn> <p2-visibility>

For a number of dims = 2 it is the same but without visibility.
So in your case, you will have class-index, x-centre, y-centre, width, height + 17 * 3 keypoint coordinates = 56

Thanks for the input, will update my posting.  However, it’s a custom dataset, not COCO.  The images are annotated using CVAT .  2 Objects per view.  Each object annotated with 4 keypoints., hence: kpt_shape: [4,3]  .  Yolo replaces the [17,3] with [4,3]  and nc=2  when it initializes, see below.
The labels have 12 columns but Yolo expects 14, so it must be looking for an additional 2 columns.  Any suggestions??
Here is one sample label txt file:
0 0.671668 0.586995 0.126533 0.0187935 0.608402 0.577598 2 0.694217 0.584489 2 0.734935 0.596391 2 0.711239 0.593663 2
5 0.535234 0.610418 0.0907717 0.0387717 0.489848 0.629804 2 0.523033 0.622391 2 0.554239 0.606946 2 0.58062 0.591033 2
This looks ok to me, but adds up to 12, not 14: see below:
Class:  5
Bbox:  0.535234  0.610418 0. 0907717  0.0387717
4 Keypoints:
0.489848 0.629804 2
0.523033 0.622391 2
0.554239 0.606946 2
0.58062 0.591033 2
Here is the initialization report:
using YAML:  /content/yaml_files/modelR.yaml
Ultralytics 8.3.15  Python-3.10.12 torch-2.4.1+cu121 CPU (Intel Xeon 2.20GHz)
engine/trainer: task=pose, mode=train, model=yolov8n-pose.yaml, data=/content/yaml_files/modelR.yaml, epochs=2, time=None, patience=100, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=train4, exist_ok=False, pretrained=yolov8n-pose.pt, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=True, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, bgr=0.0, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, copy_paste_mode=flip, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs/pose/train4
Overriding model.yaml kpt_shape=[17, 3] with kpt_shape=[4, 3]
Overriding model.yaml nc=1 with nc=2

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
